# How do I get the number of rows in relation to another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have three tables like the ones below

Applications:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | author |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | App1 |      1 |
|  2 | App2 |      1 |
|  3 | App3 |      1 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Installs:

```
+-----+----+---------------------+
| app | id | timestamp           |
+-----+----+---------------------+
|   3 |  1 | 2017-01-27 19:12:05 |
+-----+----+---------------------+
```

Users:

```
+----+----------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | username | email             | password                                                     |
+----+----------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | name     | email@address.com |                                                              |
+----+----------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Every time someone installs an app, it is added to the installs table and time stamped.

I know I can get individual app's installs by doing

```
SELECT a.name,COUNT(b.id) as installs FROM applications a,installs b WHERE a.id=3 AND b.app=3;
```

And I'll get

```
+------+----------+
| name | installs |
+------+----------+
| App3 |    30000 |
+------+----------+
```

What I would like is be able to get all the names of the apps, and the installs of the app from a certain author, in one result set like this:

```
+------+----------+
| name | installs |
+------+----------+
| App1 |    10000 |
| App2 |    20000 |
| App3 |    30000 |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: Well asked, poorly researched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a basic `GROUP BY` query with a `JOIN` and `WHERE`:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(i.id) as installs
FROM applications a LEFT JOIN
     installs i
     ON a.id = b.app
WHERE a.author = 1
GROUP BY a.name;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Your table aliases should be abbreviations for the table name, rather than random letters like `b`.
- The `JOIN` condition uses columns from both tables.
- The `LEFT JOIN` keeps all applications in for the author, even if there are no installs.

Answer (score 2):

Use `INNER JOIN` without filter's

```
SELECT a.NAME,
       Count(*) AS installs
FROM   applications a
       JOIN installs i
         ON a.id = i.app
```